# Temp table does not exists even if connection is not closed

Tags: c#, sql-server, temp-tables

I have the following code:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    connection.Open();

    var createTempTables = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[p_CreateTempTable]", connection)
    {
        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    };

    createTempTables.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", 2));
    createTempTables.ExecuteNonQuery();

    var actualCommand = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[p_Test]", connection)
    {
        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    };

    var dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Load(actualCommand.ExecuteReader());
}
```

Basically, `[dbo].[p_CreateTempTable]` selects the row matching the ID inut as parameter from a table. Then, `[dbo].[p_Test]` just selects the temp table. From what I understand, temp tables are supposed to last as long as the connection is not closed, but I always get an exception that says tha my temp table does not exists. Why is this not working ?

Note: If I instead use a text command that creates the temp table within C# instead, then the program runs with no issues. I however want to avoid doing so, since there will be more validations when creating the temp table and since the application is a WinForms, I would like to avoid recompilation everytime that logics changes.

Comment: Can you show the SQL procedure p_CreateTempTable?

Comment: A temporary table only exists for the duration of the scope it is created in. I very much suspect your 2 statements are running in separate scopes.

Comment: temporary tables created within a procedure go out of scope when the procedure finishes execution. In your code, dbo.p_Test cannot access any temp table created in dbo.p_createTempTable.

Comment: @Vernou It's a simple `SELECT INTO` statement

Comment: Doesn't matter, @RegularNormalDayGuy .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic problem here is that in SQL Server temp tables' lifetimes are bound to the batch and//or session context that created them.

What this means is that if you create a temp table within a stored procedure, then that temp table can only be seen until that stored procedure exits (so effectively, only by other stored procedures that that stored procedure calls).  This is because the stored procedure is a batch context itself so if it creates a temp table, then it becomes bound to that stored procedure's batch context.

There's only two ways around this, both inconvenient:

1. Create the temp tables at the session-level by using direct commands (ie., NOT in a stored procedure), which means that you have to include the commands in your client code (or config settings).  Or
2. Use Global temp tables instead.  Global temp tables don't really work like normal temp tables, they will persist across batches and sessions until you explicitly drop them, so you can create them in a stored procedure and they will persist.  However, now you have to worry about the same things as a regular table: what if the tables already exist?  And what if more than one user is running this stored procedure(s) at the same time?  The only advantage over regular tables is that it requires less privileges to create and drop them.

Comment: Yeah i though about using global temporary table, but have multi-user edition too, so it adds even more complexity if every user is using the same temporary table. I will probably go with option 1. Thanks a lot for your answer !

Comment: @RegularNormalDayGuy Yep, there's no easy answer.  For option 1, a trick that I have used is to store the commands to create the tables in a regular table in the database.  Then you don't have to maintain those commands in the client.  The client code just reads a row from that table and executes it to create the temp tables at the session-level.

Comment: Thats really smart. I was creating a procedure that returns the command, but I think storing those commands in a table is even better, thanks for the tip